# Can a Man trim his Unibrows(Hair Between Eyebrows) in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, hair

Assalam o Alaikum, I already know that cutting the eyebrows in Islam is Haram but what about the Unibrows(The Hair Between Eyebrows). They look very bad on my face and I have trimmed my Unibrows 2 times. But I am still not clear that It is Halal to Cut the Hair between Eyebrows because it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is permissible to remove the hairs between the two eyebrows because they are not considered eyebrows or because they are "excessive".

This is the status of the Maliki and Hanafi school (other schools I don't know).

Comment: Can you reference this please?

Comment: In Tarkhanija about the pronouns: There is nothing wrong with removing the eyebrows and the hair of the face as long as there is no pubic hair.

Al-Muhtar à Al-Durr Al-Mukhtar, vol. 6, p. 373, Saeed

There is nothing wrong with removing the eyebrows and the hair on his face, as long as he does not look like a effeminate, like that in the springs.

(Al-Fatwa Al-Hindi, Part 5, pg. 358,

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question to Hanafi scholars like 2-3 years ago and they said you can cut them since they are above the nose and not the eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it’s halal, because the hair between the two eyebrows is not considered as the hair of eyebrow - according to the most scholars